# Может ли буква З обозначать звук С?

Tags: русская-графика

1. Каждый язык имеет свою графическую систему,  в основе которой лежат правила соответствия «звук-буква».  Русская графическая система уникальна тем, что, с учетом правил обозначения мягкости согласных, звука Й, а также некоторых графических орфограмм,   она обеспечивает практически однозначное звуко-буквенное  соответствие, приближаясь к идеальному варианту.
2. В то же время в школьных учебниках последних лет мы можем встретить утверждение, что буква З может обозначать звук С (например, мороз) , а две буквы СЧ  – один звук Щ (например,счёт). Насколько корректны такие утверждения, учитывая, что один и тот же термин используется в разных ситуациях?

Например, согласно графической системе, буква З используется ДЛЯ ОБОЗНАЧЕНИЯ  звука З (твердого или мягкого), а звуку С  буква З может только  СООТВЕТСТВОВАТЬ  ПОЗИЦИОННО, если в данной позиции происходит фонетическое чередование З/С.

1. Также можно отметить, что этот вопрос ПО-РАЗНОМУ ИЗЛАГАЛСЯ в учебниках различных периодов:

А) 1971-1976 гг: «Звонкие согласные Б, В, Г, Д, З, Ж перед глухими согласными и на конце слова оглушаются, а глухие согласные П, Ф, К, Т, С, Ш перед звонкими согласными становятся звонкими. На письме указанное оглушение и озвончение НЕ ОТРАЖАЕТСЯ».

Б) 1987г:  «Полного СООТВЕТСТВИЯ букв и звуков в русском языке нет. Одни и те же буквы обозначают СВОИ звуки и другие».

В) 1997 г: «В слове союз буква З ОБОЗНАЧАЕТ звук С».

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

"Краткий справочник по современному русскому языку" под редакцией П.А.Леканта, 1995 год (стр. 148)

1. Фонематический принцип орфографии заключается в том, что буквами обозначаются фонемы (не звуки).
2. Определив, какой фонеме СООТВЕТСТВУЕТ звук в слабой позиции, ее обозначают соответствующей буквой.

Comment: Не вижу противоречия. Разве в слове "союз" не происходит "фонетического чередования З/С" ? Формулировка со ссылкой на 1971 - 76 год встречается и в современных учебниках.

Comment: Вы исходите из неверных посылок. Каждый язык имеет свою графическую систему, да. Но в основе её не обязательно лежат правила соответствия "звук - буква". Например, в русском письме основная часть правил строится на соответствиях звук - __фонема__.

Comment: "Чтобы никто не догадался"

Comment: ГРАФИКА РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА – это соответствие «звук – буква» или «фонема – буква», разницы нет. Когда мы говорим о фонетическом составе языка или о соответствии «звук-буква», нам понятие фонемы не очень-то и нужно.  ПРАВИЛА ГРАФИКИ  определяют способ обозначения мягкости согласных и звука Й, особенности употребления  букв Э/Е, туда же относятся орфограммы, связанные с шипящими, разделительные знаки.  Фонема важна в РЕАЛЬНОМ СЛОВЕ, так как именно тогда происходит ФОНЕТИЧЕСКОЕ ЧЕРЕДОВАНИЕ, которое, согласно фонологической теории, не отражается на письме.

Comment: Представьте себе, что мы при чтении будем четко проговаривать каждое слово (так называемое орфографическое чтение). Тогда  фонетического чередования не будет, можно всё писать по слуху, тогда вообще без фонемы можно обойтись.Получается, что  такая нужная для орфографии фонема приносит больше вреда, чем пользы. Теперь мы имеем  тот МИКС, который  любим  иметь во всем. Думаю, что мало кто может четко  ответить на простейшие вопросы, например: Чем фонема отличается от звука, какая нам вообще польза от этого понятия?  Сколько в нашем языке звуков, а сколько фонем? Вот А – это звук или фонема?

Comment: >*ГРАФИКА РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА – это соответствие «звук – буква» или «фонема – буква», разницы нет*

Если разницы нет, зачем тогда ваш вопрос? Пишите иногда "союз", иногда "союс" - как в данный момент захочется. (Да, если вы хотите быть последовательной, вам иногда надо будет писать и "саюс", "саюз"...)

Comment: Надо различать графику и орфографию. Графика - это выбор письменного знака для звука, например: мягкий звук Л мы обозначаем знаком ЛЬ на конце слова или перед согласной и буквами Л(Я), Л(Ю) и др. перед гласным звуком. Правила графики не относятся к конкретным словам. Орфография - это ПРАВИЛЬНАЯ запись конкретного слова. Зная правила графики (твердый звук С на конце слова обозначается буквой С) и написав "союс", мы делаем ошибку, так как это СЛАБАЯ позиция гласного - звук С имеет неполную различительную способность (он говорит: здесь З или С), и мы выбираем З по сильной позиции: союз - союзы.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что правило выбора З в слове "союз" - это "правило записи конкретного слова" (_союз_), а, скажем, для записи слова _арбуз_ уже нужно совершенно другое правило - для другого конкретного слова?

Comment: В своем ответ я использовала категории абстрактное-конкретное. Графика решает абстрактную задачу соответствия алфавита и фонетики языка - какой буквой будет обозначен каждый отдельный звук. Конкретная задача - это обозначение звука на практике, то есть в реальной речи. В словах союз/арбуз я слышу звук С. Если бы наше письмо было фонетическим, я бы его обозначала по слуху: слышу С и пишу букву С. Но наше письмо фонематическое (смысловое), поэтому звук С не вызывает у меня доверия. Он находится в слабой позиции, где возможно  чередование З/С, и я должна проверить, фонему З или С он представляет

Comment: Ну, значит правило всё-таки не очень "конкретное", не персональное для каждого слова ("проверить, фонему З или С..."), слава будде. А после проверки вы ведь примените следующее правило: "Фонему <__С__> запишем буквой С". Это и есть _правило графики_.

---------------

А что было бы при попытках записи русской речи "фонетическим письмом", вам подсказал ниже Tom_Cat. Да и сами подумайте: легко ли ученикам будет достоверно записывать "то, что слышим"  (транскрипцию)?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Насколько корректны такие утверждения, учитывая, что один и тот же термин используется в разных ситуациях?
```

А почему некорректны, если термин многозначен? Мы же используем его в нужном значении.

Обозначать - 4) Значить, иметь смысл, значение. 
Толковый словарь Ефремовой
`

Если вы обозначаете какое-либо понятие, математическую величину и т. п. каким-либо словом, буквой и т. п., значит, вы условно придаёте им значение данного понятия, величины и т. п.
Давление принято обозначать латинской буквой P. | Поскольку имя данного человека нам неизвестно, будем обозначать его далее как «мистер X». |
св.
Обозначим массу первого шара через m1, а второго через m2.
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/2974/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C2.

Точно так же и Буква Е обозначает звуки [Й], [Э],а в  слове союз буква З ОБОЗНАЧАЕТ звук С [саюс].(в младших классах не знают ослабленного а)

Всё закономерно: в 70-е не было учения о фонеме, говорили просто "оглушаются", в 80-е появилось учение о фонеме: одна и та же  буква з может обозначать(являться знаком для передачи звука)звук [з]в слове возложить и звук[с] в слове союз.В 90-е стали говорить короче, потому что к фонеме уже привыкли:«В слове союз буква З ОБОЗНАЧАЕТ звук С» = буква з позиционно соответствует звуку [с].Всё корректно , коротко и понятно. Не вижу, в чём вопрос:означает=соответствует в определённой позиции.

Comment: Учение  о фонеме появилось  не в 80-ые годы. Принцип фонемной орфографии сформулировал И. А. Бодуэн де Куртенэ в 1912 году. Это учение уже в 20-ые годы имело два направления, которые сохраняются и в наше время - СПФШ и МФШ. Например, по МФШ в слове вода фонема О, а по СПФШ  - фонема А.   Отсутствие единой теории приводит к тому, что  до сих пор в школе фонема фактически не изучается.

Comment: В 80-90-ые годы в развивающем обучении была сделана попытка обучения орфографии на основе фонологии, но широкого распространения этот проект не получил. Авторы старых учебников понимали сложность фонематической теории и старались изложить суть фонетических процессов на понятном языке, не пользуясь самим термином. А авторам современных учебников море по колено – они даже не чувствуют  сложности задачи.

Comment: ФОНЕМАТИЧЕСКИЙ ПРИНЦИП русского письма состоит в том, что буквами мы ОБОЗНАЧАЕМ не любой звук, который слышим, а ФОНЕМУ В СИЛЬНОЙ ПОЗИЦИИ. И мы не обозначаем буквами звук в слабой позиции, так как является звуком с неполной различительной способностью (позиция его сигнификативно слабая). Поэтому НЕЛЬЗЯ БУКВОЙ З ОБОЗНАЧАТЬ ЗВУК С в слабой позиции на конце слова.

Comment: Ребята, куда-то вас в "учёную муть" понесло.Я не говорю о фонематическом принципе, я говорю о появлении в ШКОЛЕ понятия фонемы, а Ваш пример, София,МОРОЗ -вообще к фонематическому(=фонетическому) принципу не относится,это морфологический(морфемный, морфематический):конечный согласный определяется по сильной позиции этой же морфемы - морозы.Буквы обозначают фонему во всех её изменениях.Большая часть букв русского алфавита обозначает на письме фонему,но не для всех фонем имеется специальная буква,а есть буквы, обозначающие аллофоны, или варианты фонемы.И везде используется термин "обозначает".

Comment: Вы, София, не захотели меня услышать, видимо, потому, что вопрос задаёте не потому, что в чём-то сомневаетесь, а затем, чтобы выслушать наши версии и вынести свой "грамотный"вердикт. Во всей научной литературе и сейчас используется термин ОБОЗНАЧАЕТ, но в разных значениях."ОБОЗНАЧАТЬ ЗВУК С в слабой позиции на конце слова" - неверно, его никто не обозначает, т.е.не отмечает, а вот сама буква З обозначает звук С, т.е."означает", является знаком для обозначения. Нужно различать значения слова  http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/2974/
посмотрите в любом другом словаре.

Comment: Я только цитаты из учебников привожу, из которых видно, как изменялась терминология. Думаю, что школьная аудитория (как ученики, так и учителя) еще не готовы к новым вершинам.  Наука должна начинаться с четких определений, а их нет. Есть один микс, смешение понятий. Например,в основе морфематического принципа лежит принцип фонематический - а не было бы фонетического чередования, так и обоих принципов не было бы. Так что лучше вернуться к прежней безыскусственной простоте, чем тонуть в малоизученной фонологии. Пусть уж буквы по-прежнему обозначают звуки, а не аллофоны.

Comment: Вы же говорите, что это неверное выражение. Но в школе именно так и говорят:"буквы  обозначают звуки", а аллофоны -для студентов, Вы же за это и ратовали - за разные уровни. Оно так и есть, ничего придумывать не надо. Но современный фонологический подход мне нравится. Полинка у нас во 2 классе двойную роль буквы Я лучше понимает, чем 9-классник, с кем я занимаюсь. И проверяемые гласные корня от чередующихся уже отличает, а он  путается. Многое зависит от учителя,кто-то по старой системе не может объяснить, кто-то по новой ясно излагает, нельзя отвергать новое, нужно его изучать.

Answer (score 0):

> обеспечивает практически однозначное звуко-буквенное соответствие, приближаясь к идеальному варианту

Если бы! Я - программист, и для того, чтобы получить ***весьма приблизительный*** орфоэпический вид слова, мне пришлось написать 350 строк кода, подкрепив это 66-ю строками описаний звучания для различных букв в различных ситуациях. А правильное произношение даёт только орфоэпический словарь.

Вот [эта программа](http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/zagruzit)
Хотите посмеяться - скачайте, посмотрите... Там есть орфографический словарь с возможностью увидеть программно сгенерированный орфоэпический вид всех словоформ.
Для практических потребностей этого хватает, но до настоящего орфоэпического словаря ох как далеко...

Comment: Здесь речь идет  о другом, задача намного проще. Перед нами лежит алфавит из 33 букв и перечень звуков согласно фонетической системе русского языка (допустим, 6 гласных и 42 согласных). Мы их сравниваем и определяем служебные обязанности букв. В идеале каждый звук должен иметь собственную букву или набор букв, тогда звуко-буквенная система будет однозначной. И вот русская графическая система весьма близка к такому идеалу. Таким образом, в этой задаче нет слов - только звуки и буквы, а поэтому нет и орфоэпии.

Comment: Возможно, между нами есть разнобой в терминологии.  
Если Вы считаете равенство 33=48 близким к идеалу - пожалуйста, я не в курсе, как с этим обстоит в других языках...  
А в моём конкретном случает передо мной лежит орфографический словарь из ~100 000 словарных статей, порождающий ~3 000 000 словоформ и записанный 33-я буквами. Мне нужно получить орфоэпический вид. Задача не кажется тривиальной.

Comment: ЗЗ=48 - это совсем не идеал. Идеал - это 48=48. Дело в том, что мы используем не только буквы, но и СОЧЕТАНИЯ букв. Например, у нас 15 пар твердых/мягких согласных, всего 30 звуков. Мягкие согласные своих букв не имеют и обозначаются сочетанием букв: мел - мель, лук - люк. Так и приближаемся к идеалу. Картину немного портят непарные шипящие и два разделительных знака, но для них имеются специальные графические правила. Причиной же большинства орфографических правил является орфоэпия, которая обеспечивает слову удобное произношение, но при этом частично искажает его смысловые возможности.

Comment: Мне кажется, правильнее говорить здесь о _фонетическом виде_ слова, а не об _орфоэпическом_ (орфоэпический менее формален, предполагает гораздо более глубокий семантический и исторический анализ).

Comment: Спасибо - таки разнобой в терминологии, т.е. говорилось о разных вещах.